# How to set the shape used for different groups in an R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to have different shapes depending on the values of some variables in R. Actually, a combination of variables. I like to give an exact shape number ( stored as s) to the combination.

I already tried to generate a new variable that sums the shape I want.

```
#gen some example code
c <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
d <- c('firstsecond', 'firstfirst', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower')
e <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
f <- c('w', 'v','w', 'v')
df <- cbind(c,d,e,f)
df<- as.data.frame(df)
df$e <- as.numeric(df$e)
orderd <- rev(c( 'firstfirst', 'firstsecond', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower' ))
df<- within(df, d <- factor(d, levels=orderd))
```

My current solution approach is that I try to set shape in a variable s:

```
library(data.table)
    df <- setDT(df)
    df$c <- as.character(df$c)
    df$f <- as.character(df$f)
    df[c %chin% c('a') & f %chin% c('w') , s := 16  ]
    df[c %chin% c('a') & f %chin% c('v') , s := 1  ]
    df[c %chin% c('b') & f %chin% c('w') , s := 17  ]
    df[c %chin% c('b') & f %chin% c('v'), s := 2  ]
```

However all shapes are the same :( they do not differ by group, as I would like them to do.

```
#plotting it:
library(ggplot2)
    p<- ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f)) +
      geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), shape = s) +
      theme_bw() + 
      facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
      coord_flip() +
      scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
      geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2)
    p
```

Comment: you need to specify `shape` (as a `factor`, since it will error with `numeric`) within `aes`, not outside

Comment: Well boundyball, sure in aesthetics, that makes sense. But now it gives a weird image, I also need to add a last row : `p<- ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f, shape = as.factor(s))) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 2.5, hjust=1.05, vjust=1.2) + 
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(17,16,2,1))`. I just wonder if there is a shorter way?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include additional code, since it's difficult to read or format in comments

Comment: If the variable `s` represents the shapes you want to plot, use `scale_shape_identity()` (if using this function you actually don't want to make things into a factor first, although usually that's the case for shapes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below uses the pre-existing `c` and `f` columns to generate the shape mapping, without creating a separate `s` column. 
    library(ggplot2)

```
#gen some example code
c <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
d <- c('firstsecond', 'firstfirst', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower')
e <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
f <- c('w', 'v','w', 'v')
df <- data.frame(c,d,e,f)

orderd <- rev(c( 'firstfirst', 'firstsecond', 'lowerupper', 'lowerlower' ))
df$d <- factor(df$d, levels=orderd)

ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, color = f, shape=interaction(c,f))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e)), size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(size=interaction(c,f))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = f), colour="white", size = 5, vjust=0.4) +
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=15:18) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(5,6,5,7)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(shape="Shape Title", colour="Colour Title") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3)),
         colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3, linetype=0)),
         size=FALSE)
```

[image]

Note: In the code above, the `size` aesthetic is solely to make each shape marker roughly the same physical size. At any given `size` specification, the square and triangle markers look bigger than the circle and diamond markers. I used the `size` aesthetic to specify custom sizes (in `scale_size_manual`) for each shape. If you don't want to do this, or want to use different shapes, then you can remove the size aesthetic from the code.

If you decide you want the labels placed below, rather than within, the point markers, I suggest using the `nudge` arguments, rather than messing with `vjust` and `hjust`, which can give unpredictable results. For example:

```
geom_text(aes(label = f), colour = "black", size = 3, nudge_x = -0.2) +
```

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment, to have a separate color scale for the text labels, we can use the [`ggnewscale` package](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale). Note in the code below that we now place the color aesthetics in the geoms to which they apply, rather than into the main call to `ggplot`:

```
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(df, aes(x = d, y = e, shape=interaction(c,f))) +
  geom_linerange(aes(min = e - 1.95 * sqrt(e), max = e + 1.95 * sqrt(e), color = f), 
                 size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(size=interaction(c,f), color = f)) +
  facet_wrap(c ~ ., scales = "free", nrow = 5, strip.position = "left") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(name="Colour Title", begin = 0.75 , end = 0) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0, 1, 17, 18)) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(5,6,5,7)) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_text(aes(label = f, colour=f), size = 5, vjust=0.4, show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "white")) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(shape="Shape Title") +
  guides(shape=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3)),
         size=FALSE)
```

[image]

Another option for having more than one color scale is the [`relayer` package](https://github.com/clauswilke/relayer). Note that ggplot is not inherently designed to have more than one scale for a given aesthetic and both of these packages are experimental.

Comment: Thank you! But I do need 4 different shapes, even though the Color gives additional info on one of the shapes‘ dimensions!

Comment: Short follow up: If using my shapes I have filled and unfilled shapes. Can I somehow type (with 'geom_text' in white when it is a "full collared shape" (16,17) and in black if it is an "empty" shape (1,2)?

Comment: I have a short follow up to my previous question: Is it somehow possible to change the legend in a way that I have a green triangle and a purple dot representing colour?